# opening fm radio from the android template

Tags: android

I am trying to create a very simple app like Tune-In with just one radio station for example.

I have tried to stream the URL from SWF, but SWF not work on android.

my code for radio stream like this :-

```
<embed width="395" height="20" flashvars="file=http://radio.arabhosters.com:8015/;stream.nsv&amp;type=mp3&amp;volume=20&amp;autostart=true" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="ply" id="ply" style="undefined; margin-bottom: 0px;" src="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

Apologize for this quite vague question, but I haven't found anything well-documented on this specific matter.

how can i open this on my template on android.

Comment: You need to figure out a way to play the SHOUTcast stream (http://radio.arabhosters.com:8015/), rather than embedding the Flash player within your application.

Comment: @James Scholes my site is blancofm.com and i have stream like this (http://radio.arabhosters.com:8015)

Comment: So you're trying to stream your radio station via a web page on Android devices, rather than play the stream within an Android application?

Comment: @James Scholes yes how can i do this ?

Comment: I was going to suggest using the HTML5 audio element, but support for MP3 streaming is sketchy at best.  Hopefully someone else has an alternative solution.

Comment: @James Scholes i will try but the same problem

Comment: i will try this http://146.185.28.245:8015/listen.pls but not work